# Are indexes in RavenDB and relational database indexs works the same?

Tags: ravendb

I am quite new of RavenDB and I am trying to understand how indexes works in RavenDB. I found a very good explanation on relational database indexing from this" [How does database indexing work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108/how-does-database-indexing-work)" . But i was wondering are the indexes in RavenDB works the same as the relational database's indexes ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kekewong,
No, they work in drastically different fashion.
They are built in the background, offer full text search support, and are stored using a different format than most db indexes.

Comment: Is there any external resources or links that i can read about how it works?

Comment: @kekewong: I'd look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602253/how-does-lucene-index-documents).