# What is the time complexity of using retainAll() function between List and HashMap?

Tags: java, algorithm, arraylist, hashmap, big-o

Let's say i have a nested List which contains n^2 element in it and also i have a HashMap which contains n^2 keys in it. I want to get common elements between the list and hashmap with using `retainAll()` function. What is the time complexity of retainAll() in this case?

```
List<List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
Map<List<Integer>, Integer> hashmap = new HashMap<List<Integer>, Integer>();
list.retainAll(hashmap);
```

To get the commons,i'm using this loop but it has n^2 complexity.

```
List<List<Integer>> commons = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        if (hashmap.get(list.get(i)) != null) {
            commons.add(list.get(i));
        }
    }
```

Also if you have an algorithm which has better time complexity  to get intersection of them, i need it.

**EDIT :**
Actually the problem is , i have a list of integers size of n . But i divided that list into sublists and sublists count became n^2. Since i want to find out that hashmap contains every sublist as a key in it, i used n^2 in question. But it's too big according to my whole project. I'm searching complexity decreasing ways.

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24754881/what-is-the-time-and-space-complexity-of-method-retainall-when-used-on-hashsets)

Comment: @GuilhermeSchaidhauerCastro I checked it before this post but I couldn't be sure it's the same. HashSet and HashMap may cause difference. Also i couldn't get the answer clearly.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I mean if you have `n^2` items in the list then the complexity is `O(n^2)`, although this a really weird thing to say. Usually `n` is the size of the collection, so the time complexity of `retainAll` is consider `O(n)`.

It's impossible to have an algorithm that produces a better time complexity for this, as far as I can think of. You have to iterate the list at least once...

What you can do is switch your data structure. Read more: [Data structures for fast intersection operations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39154817/data-structures-for-fast-intersection-operations)

Comment: Thank you @Rubydesic. Actually the problem is , i have a list of integers size of n . But i divided that list into sublists and sublists count became n^2. Since i want to find out that hashmap contains every sublist as a key in it, i used n^2 in question. But it's too big according to my whole project. I'm searching complexity decreasing ways.