# OrientDB: FullText indexes vs Lucene FullText indexes

Tags: lucene, full-text-search, orientdb

OrientDB has two types of full-text indexes: one is [their own implementation](http://orientdb.com/docs/last/FullTextIndex.html) and the second one is [Lucene implementation](http://orientdb.com/docs/last/Full-Text-Index.html). However it is absolutely unclear what I should use.

I understand that Lucene provides more features. However what if these features are not required. Should I go with standard full-text indexes or with Lucene? Then obviously performance is the main question.

Comment: Could you specify your information retrieval needs ?
Do you need morphology? Do you need advanced linguistic capabilities? Or do you need something simple such as an Index and maybe  "ignore case".
And about Lucene, it's a very fast engine, you can read about it here: https://lucene.apache.org/core/

Comment: @user1050389 I mentioned in the question that any advanced features are not required. I know that Lucene is a fast engine but I was thinking that these indexes can be faster and more lightweight because they provide less features and hence need to do less work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The indices "FULL TEXT" with engine LUCENE
provides good full-text indexes, but cannot be used to index other types. It is durable, transactional and supports range queries.
More information about lucene see [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602253/how-does-lucene-index-documents).

The indices "FULL TEXT" with engine SB-TREE 
the index is created with the algorithm that is based on the B-Tree index algorithm. It has been adapted with several optimizations, which relate to data insertion and range queries. As is the case with all other tree-based indexes, SB-Tree index algorithm experiences log(N) complexity, but the base to this logarithm is about 500. This indexing algorithm provides a good mix of features, similar to the features available from other index types. It is good for general use and is durable, transactional and supports range queries.

a simple example that compares the speed:

- DB one: 100000 top of Class Person with property name with value "the name is 1...n " and Lucene index on this property
- DB one: 100000 top of Class Person with property name with value "the name is 1...n " and sbtree index on this property

On one db: `select from Person where name LUCENE "49000"` return one record --> Query executed in 0.039 sec.

Db on two: `select from Persona where name = "49000"` return one record --> Query executed in 1.364 sec