# How to implement lock-free skip list

Tags: algorithm, lock-free, skip-lists

I need to implement a lock-free skip list. I tried to look for papers. Unfortunatly all I found was lock-free single linked lists (in many flavors). However how to implement lock-free skip list?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Lock-free skip lists are described in the book [The Art of Multiprocessor Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0123705916), and the technical report [Practical lock-freedom](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/techreports/UCAM-CL-TR-579.pdf), which is based on a PhD thesis on the subject. The skip list discussion begins on page 53. An example implementation, based on these sources, is included in [this google code project](http://code.google.com/p/nbds/).

There are related discussions, links to literature and implementations (not necessarily lock-free) in the SO questions [Skip List vs. Binary Tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/256511/skip-list-vs-binary-tree), and [Skip Lists - ever used them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234560/skip-lists-ever-used-them).

Answer (score 5):

[This paper](http://www.cs.tau.ac.il/~shanir/nir-pubs-web/Papers/OPODIS2006-BA.pdf) presents a lock-free and wait-free skip list. It's straightforward to implement - I implemented this a few weeks ago as part of the [Intel Threading Challenge 2010](http://software.intel.com/en-us/contests/threading-challenge-prof-2010/codecontest.php) (see the SkipList tab halfway down the page.)

Java includes an implementation of a concurrent skip list, [java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentSkipListMap](http://www.koders.com/java/fid1D71A270A88EDEEE6CC29213D1D9AC3DECE413D2.aspx?s=file%3Asemap*.java).

Comment: Is your code available anywhere (it's not obvious to me on the Intel site as to where to get it.)

Comment: The algorithm in the paper referred to is neither lock-free nor wait-free.

Comment: Jonatan, I just took a quick glimpse at the paper again and you may be right. I read so many papers at the time I must have got my wires crossed. That was over two years ago, so I no longer recall which paper I had in mind when thinking of the lock and wait free list.

Comment: @mdma: In your implementation, for the insert operation, there doesn't seem to be a linearization point, compared to the paper by Shavit et al. Can this cause any problems for a concurrent read operation?